# How to append properties of another object to a json object without copying all the properties in the target json object

Tags: c#, .net, json

So here is the scenario, I have a class which is being serialized to a json object:

```
public classA
{
    [JsonProperty("A")]
        public string A { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("B")]
        public string B { get; set; }
}
```

I am serializing it to a json string like below:

```
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new classA
        {
            A = "stingAAAA",
            B = "stringBBBBB"
        });
```

Now, I have another class:

```
public classB
{
    [JsonProperty("C")]
    public string C { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("D")]
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

I want to append the properties of `ClassB` object to the json string being generated but without copying all the properties (C and D) to `ClassA`. So basically the final json string should treat properties of ClassB object as if they were the properties of ClassA itsef. Is it even possible?

Comment: Something like this is no good for your? ``public string C { get { return _b.C; } set { _b.C = value; } }``

Comment: `classB` could derive from `classA` : `class clasB:classA`. This way `classB` will have properties of `classA`

Comment: @PablonotPicasso actually ClassA is a Struct and not a Class for some reasons. So even though this would have been a good option, I cannot do it unfortunately.

Comment: @RandRandom not sure if I got the point here.

Comment: @tavier see my answer

Comment: You could use a third class that has the properties you want in the json object and assign those properties with values from `classA` and `classB`.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions:

1.Create dictionary with values from both objects

2.Create new class with 2 properties (classA and classB)

```
var a = new classA { A = "stingAAAA", B = "stringBBBBB" };
var b = new classB { C = "CCC", D = "DDD" };
```

1:

```
var dictA = a.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.PropertyName ?? x.Name, y => y.GetValue(a));
var dictB = b.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.PropertyName ?? x.Name, y => y.GetValue(b));

var result = new[] { dictA, dictB }.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
// Result: {"A":"stingAAAA","B":"stringBBBBB","C":"CCC","D2":"DDD"}
```

2:

```
var newClass = new { ClassA = a, ClassB = b };
var res2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newClass);
// Result: {"ClassA":{"A":"stingAAAA","B":"stringBBBBB"},"ClassB":{"C":"CCC","D2":"DDD"}}
```

Both however have disadvantages.

1 - there will be problem if both classA and classB would have properties with the same name (or JsonPropertyAttribute)

2 - you result will have 2 properties and all properties you need will be inside of them.